# Number of invertible elements in a quadratic extension of a finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

> Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$ be a prime and let us denote $N=p^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\alpha$ be the larger root of the qudratic $q(x)=x^2+ax+1$ where $a\in 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $a^2>4$. Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. How many elements are there in the quotient ring $S=(R/NR)^*$?

If we were asked about the original ring, I would say $\varphi(N)$ (elements disjoint to $N$ as $S=\mathbb{Z}_N^*$). However here we might have more elements? Is there a rigorous way to count them?

**edit:** Following the comments I have edited the question and added several more assumptions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Then it contains only two elements

Comment: Yes. 0 is non-invertible. 1 of course is. $(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})^2\equiv 1+0\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+0$ (as far as I understand $2\equiv 0$ so $"\frac 12"$ is 0). Then out of $2^2$ possible elements only 2 are invertible

Comment: Because two elements of the ring are equivalent under the quotient iff their difference is $2a+\frac{2}{\sqrt 2} b\in 2\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}]$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay I see what you mean. I changed the question to avoid such scenarios. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Is the quadratic polynomial in $\Bbb Z[X]$, or in an arbitrary polynomial ring? For rings of integers of number fields the question is better, and we can use the norm.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes we can assume the polynomial is in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. If I'm not wrong it indeed gives a lower bound on the cardinality as $a+o\alpha$ is invertible for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ but of course it's not a tight one (e.g. if $p(x)=x^2-3$, we could say that $(2-\sqrt 3)(2+\sqrt 3)=1$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde actually can we use Dirichlet unit theorem?

Comment: Not in general. You first need to edit your post accordingly (which coefficients has the quadratic polynomial, is it monic, is $R$ the ring of integers of a quadratic number field, etc.).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. I've edited the question and added several more assumptions.